Is there a way to safely import a Python module from untrusted user input?
I want to dynamically import a module, based on untrusted user input, and be confident that the submodule that I will import comes from a specific trusted module directory.
I intend to process user input in the following way :
import importlib
submodule_name = user_input.split(".")[0]

# Are the 2 following lines safe ? (considering I trust all code in `trusted_directory`)
imported_module = importlib.import_module(f"trusted_directory.{submodule_name}")
imported_module.main()

trusted_directory will contain pyhon modules that I write myself, each of them implementing a main() function. I'm mainly worried about two things :

Directory traversal : Are there values for user_input that lead to a module outside of trusted_directory to be imported ?
Characters that are not dots having a special meaning in imports : PEP 328 only mentions dots. Is there any other PEP that introduces other special-meaning characters in imports ?

More generally, is my approach safe ? Can you find a way to break out of trustred_directory ? Is there any recommended sanitation method for Python imports that I did not find ?
I looked around for specs about absolute/relative imports in python and could only find PEP 323. From my understanding of this spec, it seems that my approach is safe, but I'm worried I missed other important bits of specification.

maybe user should select module from list - not write it manually.

Your trusted directory consists of trusted files. You can know the list of trusted filenames (using something like iterdir) and then test every user input against that trusted list. If you are very paranoid, you can even avoid importing based on user input import_module(f"trusted_directory.{user_input}") and import based on some conditions instead: if 'audio' in user_input: import_module("trusted_directory.audio"). Depends on your needs.

You should be checking if the module even exists. Doing so will negate any other issues, because you aren't going to load anything unless it's in the trusted directory.
Something like this:
import importlib, glob

module = input('Input a module name: ')

while f'{module}.py' not in glob.glob('*.py', root_dir='trusted_directory'):
    module = input(f'{module} does not exist. Try again: ')
    
module = importlib.import_module(f"trusted_directory.{module}")
module.main()

